# detect the control/view at the point of touch

Tags: iphone, uiview, uicontrol, touch-event

When the touch happens, I can get the CGPoint from where the touch was happening. Now, I want to know what is the UI element (be it a control or view) at the spot, is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`-[UIView hitTest:withEvent:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) method:

> Returns the farthest descendant of the receiver in the view hierarchy (including itself) that contains a specified point.

Comment: cool thanks! even further, how can I tell if a given CGPoint is within the overlap rect of two views? or maybe before that, how can I get the overlap rect of two views?

Comment: Check out CGRectIntersection and CGRectContainsPoint in [CGGeometry Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html).  You'll also need [`-[UIView convertRect:fromView:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCDBGGG).